# How to redirect multiline output into mailx body of message?

Tags: bash, centos8, mailx

I'm trying to redirect the output of a command into mailx.

```
if grep -B 1 line $curccrtpick; then
    grep -B 1 line $curccrtpick | head -2 > tempmsg
    mail -s "String found in $curccrtpick" -r test@test.com dummy@test.com < tempmsg
    #rm tempmsg
else
    echo nothing
fi
```

But it appears as a binary file in the form of an attachment (ATT00001.bin)

When I run

```
tr -d '[\015\200-\377]' < tempmsg > tempmsg1
```

and redirect that file into mailx I receive the email in a one liner:

```
thefirstlinethesecondline
```

when there should be two

```
thefirstline
thesecondline
```

---

Comment: can you `read -r -d '' content < tempmsg; printf '%q\n' "$content"` and add the output to the question ?

Comment: @fravadona output has been added. Thank you

Comment: In UNIX terms, a file that doesn't end with the `\n` character is considered a binary file. The last `\n` of "$curccrtpick" has been stripped somewhere before in the code

Comment: @fravadona I've updated with latest results.

Comment: you can quickfix the problem with `echo >> tempmsg1` but you should search where the last newline disappeared (probably in a `$( )`)

Comment: @fravadona I looked at the file I was grepping and the trailing \n is being stripped. Using >> doesn't keep the trailing \n.. Using this:  grep -B 1 line $curccrtpick | head -2 > tempmsg && echo "EOF" >> tempmsg ... give the trailing \nEOF

Comment: Sorry, the read command is `IFS=''  read -r -d '' content < tempmsg; printf '%q\n' "$content"` instead, can you update the output?

Comment: First set     LANG="en_US.UTF8" ; export LANG

Answer (score 0):

This is the logic that worked for me. Utilizing sendmail seems more appropriate than mailx.

```
if grep -B 1 Retry $curpickccsb; then
        stringLine1=$(grep -B 1 Line $curpickccsb | head -1)
        stringLine2=$(grep Line $curpickccsb | head -1)
        echo -e "String located in $curpickccsb. Sending email notification."
        echo -e "Content-Type: text/plain\r\nFrom: no-reply@domain.com\r\nSubject: String in $curpickccsb\r\n\r\n'$stringLine1'\r\n'$stringLine2'\r\n" | sendmail -f no-reply@domain.com test@domain.com
else
        echo -e "No errors located in $curpickccsb"
fi
```